# convert an object list with list to a single list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, listcollectionview

I have an object list, containing objects like:

```
Userobject{
    username
    userage
...
    userrolesList // is a List<userrole>
}

userrole{
    rolid
    rolname
    rolcommission
}
```

`userrolesList` can have one or more `userroleobjects`.

I need to send this list to another system, but the other system only accepts a list of objects like:

```
Userobject{
    username
    userage
...
    userroleobject // is a userrole object
}

userrole{
    rolid
    rolname
    rolcommission
}
```

In this case if one user have 10 roles I need to send 10 different objects to the other system. Any suggestion how I can make this easily and not affect the performance?

Comment: why not iterate all 10 roles after sending to parse them to userroleobject.

Comment: keep a property in Userobject, type of Object and in get return userrolesList as a single object and send

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy with LINQ query syntax:

```
var results = from user in userObjects
              from role in user.UserRolesList
              select new OtherSystemUserObject
              {
                  UserAge = user.UserAge,
                  UserName = user.UserName,
                  UserRole = role
                  // other mapping stuff...
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not very logical, my friend. However, what comes to my mind is: You can create a class with the class model you need to send an then iterate through the `userrolelist` casting each element to a single `userrole` object. Like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < userobject.userroleslist.Count ; i++)
{
    var userrole = userobject.userroleslist[i];
    //  Map your object with this userrole variable
}
```